# Is there a way to divide these two int variables and get a valid float value, Itried double but its not working properly, thanks

Tags: c

I'm trying to divide two int variables and get a float, but I don't know what the right way of doing it without losing any value.

I tried using double but its just messing it up

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    double c;
    a = 5;
    b = 2;
    c = a / b;
    printf("%lf", c);
//output: 2.000000
}
```

This should be 2.500000

Comment: Have you tried: `c = ((double) a)/ b;`?

Comment: Side note: cast operator has stronger precedence, so the additional parentheses can be left out: `c = (double)a / b;`